# Configure Lotus Notes to only beep for messages in my inbox

Tags: lotus-notes

By default, Lotus Notes beeps and displays a system tray icon whenever it receives an email. I've configured Notes with filters that automatically file emails I don't care about in folders so that I don't see them in my Inbox. However, Notes still beeps for those emails even though they are being auto-filed.

Is there any way to configure Notes to only beep for emails that arrive in the Inbox, not other folders?

I'm using Lotus Notes 8.5.3FP2 on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible (I even tried testing using Notes Minder).

A slightly over engineered work around might be to write a PowerShell/C# app using the Notes COM/OLE object. However if you have a friendly Notes admin, they can expose your mailbox as an IMAP account, then there's a lot of code/3rd party apps to watch inboxes.